# Android - infinite ruler/slider to change int value

Tags: android, android-view, android-library, rulers

Does anyone know a library that adds a similar slider to an application to change the value of a number?

[image]

I need an element that allows itself to scroll indefinitely and change the value up/down (without a maximum and minimum value)

I tried to google similar libraries, but everywhere there is a scrolling limit in the form of a minimum and maximum value

Comment: try to look here https://android-arsenal.com/